# Дата, отличная от текущей. DateTime() PHP

Tags: php, datetime

Есть $currentDateTime = new DateTime(); Т.е. текущая дата.

Необходимо получить дату, которая была сутки назад (хранилась в DateTime).

Возможно ли прямо в конструкторе указать, чтобы при создании экземпляра, дата была отличная от текущей на сутки.

Какие способы есть задания подобных дат?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.sub.php  и https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.modify.php

Comment: Вариант с модификацией даты подходит, но сперва стоит обратить внимание на форматы даты, которые поддерживает конструктор DateTime https://www.php.net/manual/ru/datetime.formats.relative.php.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

как ни банально

```
<?php
$yesterday = new DateTime('- 24 hours');
var_dump($yesterday->format('Y-m-d H:m:s'));
?>
```